# CollectionView selection doesn't work

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to select a cell in my UICollectionView but it doesn't work. I've watched a lot of tutorials but none helped, I did exactly the same as them but mine doesn't work. I hope someone can help me!

CollectionView Create Code:

```
func createCollectionView() {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width / 2.75, height: view.frame.size.width / 2.75)
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical

    photoCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width / 1.2, height: view.frame.size.height - biographyLabel.center.y - 75 -
        navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height), collectionViewLayout: layout)
    photoCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    photoCollectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    photoCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    photoCollectionView.allowsSelection = true
    photoCollectionView.delegate = self
    photoCollectionView.dataSource = self
    photoCollectionView.register(PhotosCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "photoCell")
    photoCollectionView.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 2, y: view.frame.size.height - (photoCollectionView.frame.size.height / 2) - navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height)

    view.addSubview(photoCollectionView)
}
```

Select Code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("test")
}
```

Thanks for helping!

UPDATE:

Create cell code:

```
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0) {
        if(scrollView.frame.size.height == view.frame.size.height - navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height - tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.size.height) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                self.coverImage.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height + (self.coverImage.frame.size.height / 2))
                self.profileImage.center = CGPoint(x: self.coverImage.center.x, y: self.coverImage.center.y + (self.coverImage.frame.size.height / 2))
                self.verifiedLogo.center = CGPoint(x: self.profileImage.center.x + (self.profileImage.frame.size.width / 3), y: self.profileImage.center.y - (self.profileImage.frame.size.height / 3))
                self.usernameLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.profileImage.center.y + (self.profileImage.frame.size.height / 2) + (self.usernameLabel.frame.size.height / 2))
                self.biographyLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.usernameLabel.center.y + (self.usernameLabel.frame.size.height / 2) + (self.biographyLabel.frame.size.height / 2))
                self.biographyTextfield.center = self.biographyLabel.center
                self.biographyCharactersLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.biographyTextfield.center.y + self.biographyCharactersLabel.frame.size.height)
                self.editImagesLogo.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width - self.editImagesLogo.frame.size.width, y: self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height + (self.editImagesLogo.frame.size.height * 2))
                self.editBiographyImage.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width - (self.editBiographyImage.frame.size.width * 1.5), y: self.biographyLabel.center.y)
                self.editImagesView.center = CGPoint(x: self.editImagesLogo.center.x + (self.editImagesLogo.frame.size.width / 2) - (self.editImagesView.frame.size.width / 2), y: self.editImagesLogo.center.y + (self.editImagesLogo.frame.size.height / 2) + (self.editImagesView.frame.size.height / 2))
                self.doneImage.center = self.editBiographyImage.center
                self.nextImage.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width - (self.nextImage.frame.size.width / 1.5), y: self.view.frame.size.height - (self.nextImage.frame.size.height / 1.25) -
                    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height)

                self.photoCollectionView.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height - self.biographyLabel.center.y - 75 - self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height
                self.photoCollectionView.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.size.height - (self.photoCollectionView.frame.size.height / 2) - self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height)
            }, completion: { (true) in
                self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(false, animated: false)

                for barButtons in self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items! {
                    barButtons.isEnabled = true
                }
            })
        }
    }else{
        if(scrollView.frame.size.height == self.view.frame.size.height - self.biographyLabel.center.y - 75 - self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height) {
            navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)

            for barButtons in tabBarController!.tabBar.items! {
                barButtons.isEnabled = false
            }

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                self.coverImage.center.y = -(self.coverImage.frame.size.height / 2)
                self.profileImage.center.y = -(self.profileImage.frame.size.height / 2)
                self.verifiedLogo.center.y = -(self.verifiedLogo.frame.size.height / 2)
                self.usernameLabel.center.y = -(self.usernameLabel.frame.size.height / 2)
                self.biographyLabel.center.y = -(self.biographyLabel.frame.size.height / 2)
                self.biographyTextfield.center.y = -(self.biographyTextfield.frame.size.height / 2)
                self.doneImage.center.y = -(self.doneImage.frame.size.height / 2)
                self.biographyCharactersLabel.center.y = -(self.biographyCharactersLabel.frame.size.height / 2)
                self.editImagesLogo.center.y = -(self.editImagesLogo.frame.size.height / 2)
                self.editBiographyImage.center.y = -(self.editBiographyImage.frame.size.height / 2)
                self.editImagesView.center.y = -(self.editImagesView.frame.size.height / 2)
                self.nextImage.center.y = -(self.nextImage.frame.size.height / 2)

                self.photoCollectionView.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height - self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height - self.tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.size.height
                self.photoCollectionView.center = self.view.center
            })
        }
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(photoLinks.isEmpty) {
        photoCollectionView.isHidden = true

        return 0
    }else{
        photoCollectionView.isHidden = false

        return photoLinks.count
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = photoCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photoCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotosCollectionViewCell

    cell.awakeFromNib()

    cell.photoImage.image = nil

    if(loadedPhotos.count == photoLinks.count) {
        cell.photoImage.image = loadedPhotos[indexPath.row]
    }else{
        let photoLink = photoLinks[indexPath.row]

        let url = URL(string: photoLink)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

            if(error != nil){
                print(error as Any)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                    let image = downloadedImage

                    cell.photoImage.image = image
                    self.loadedPhotos.append(image)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: put a breakpoint there in didselect method and chck isnt it calling when you tap on any cell

Comment: It does nothing so the method isn't called when I tap on a cell.

Comment: update cellForRowAtIndexPath method also

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Update cellForRowAtIndexPath code also in your question  and other method , where you adding anything with cell like size etc

Comment: Oh ok, I'll do it right now

Comment: Try adding this line of code `photoCollectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` in your  `createCollectionView()`

Comment: Already tried that but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding `view.gestureRecognizers?.removeAll()` in the createCollectionView function.